# How to close a Terminal window using bash and AppleScript without using SystemEvents?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, applescript

### Background

I am trying to create a script that when executed, opens a new *Terminal.app* window executes the desired commands and closes the window when complete.

One solution was to use `SystemEvents` in the AppleScript in order to send `CMD+w` to the opened terminal window when the process was complete, however, with the new security features of macOS Catalina, when prompted to send keystrokes to the terminal window, the system requires accessibility permissions before it can send `CMD+w` to the opened window. Thus, this is not a desirable solution.

Another possible solution was to modify the `shellExitAction` of the current profile for the Terminal.app window from 2 to 0, so that when the command `exit` is passed, the window closes. However, because of the preferences being cached, the plist file for Terminal is not updated when the desired `defaults write` command is executed. I also, understand that the `shellExitAction` is not a global property to the Terminal plist file, its hierarchy is `{ "Window Settings" = { "Basic" = { shellExitAction = 2; }; }; }` and not `{ shellExitAction = 2 }`. **So, this solution isn't working ask expected.**

`terminal`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage:
#     terminal                   Opens the current directory in a new terminal window
#     terminal [PATH]            Open PATH in a new terminal window
#     terminal [CMD]             Open a new terminal window and execute CMD
#     terminal [PATH] [CMD]      Opens a new terminal window @ the PATH and executes CMD
#
# Example:
#     terminal ~/Code/HelloWorld ./setup.sh

function terminal() {
    local cmd=""
    local wd="$PWD"
    local args="$*"

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        wd="$1"
        args="${*:2}"
    fi

    if [ -n "$args" ]; then
        cmd="$args"
    fi

    # Force Terminal window to close on command "exit"
    # Currently, does not achieve the desireable result because the 
    # com.apple.terminal plist file is not reloaded after the 
    # write command is executed.
    sudo defaults read com.apple.terminal shellExitAction &> /dev/null || {
        sudo defaults write com.apple.terminal shellExitAction -int 0
    }

    defaults read com.apple.terminal shellExitAction &> /dev/null || {
        defaults write com.apple.terminal shellExitAction -int 0
    }

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    osascript <<EOF
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell window 1
        do script "cd $wd ; $cmd ; exit"
        repeat while busy
            delay 1
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
EOF
}

terminal "$@"
```

### Issue

Given the two possible non-desirable solutions I have listed above, how could I modify the above script in a way that would close the current window when the `do script` action is completed without having to ask for accessability permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Terminal.app* is scriptable with AppleScript, so its `window` objects respond to the command **`close`**, e.g.

```
tell application id "com.apple.Terminal" to close the front window
```

Put into the context from your example script:

```sh
osascript <<-EOF
tell application "Terminal" to tell the front window
        set T to do script "cd $wd; $cmd"
        repeat
            delay 1
            if not busy of T then exit repeat
        end repeat        
        close it
end tell
EOF
```

---

**Addendum:** View [my answer to a subsequent question](https://superuser.com/a/1519267/849016) that shows how to target a specific window (rather than just the `front window`) using the AppleScript reference returned by invoking `do script`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Now, if I wanted to find the `PID` of the Terminal window that was just opened, how would I do that?

Comment: yeah your right, and yes,  I meant `pid`.

Comment: In AppleScript, the `pid` is obtained through your old friend, _System Events_, which refers to it as the `unix id`.  In `bash`, you can get the `pid` using the `ps` command.

Comment: Also, involving your AppleScript, it appears to be closing the window before the script completes itself. For example, passing `sleep 25` in place of `$cmd` it will close the window before `sleep 25` is complete.

Comment: Also, `lsappinfo info 'Terminal' -only pid` returns only 1 pid. What if I have two Terminal windows opened?

Comment: I was using your AppleScript and simply demonstrating how to use the command.  Functionally, it didn't alter anything in your script (I only made a small syntax adjustment for stylistic purposes).  If you have a means that successfully allows you to detect when a `do script` command is complete, then you need to use that.  If not, that's a question that probably has many solutions, none of which will be perfect.  You're using the `busy` property of a window, which I'm fairly certain has not been reliable since at least High Sierra.