# How do I target and close a specific Terminal window in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, applescript

### Background

Given the below `terminal` script, I want to modify the `osascript` so that instead of targeting the `front window` I am targeting the **specific window** that is opened from the AppleScript.

`terminal`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage:
#     terminal [CMD]             Open a new terminal window and execute CMD
#
# Example:
#     terminal cd "sleep 100"

terminal() {

    # Mac OS only
    [ "$(uname -s)" != "Darwin" ] && {
        echo 'Mac OS Only'
        return
    }

    local cmd=""
    local args="$*"

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    if [ -n "$args" ]; then
        cmd="$args"
    fi

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    osascript <<EOF
tell application "Terminal" to tell the front window
    set w to do script "$cmd"
    repeat
        delay 1
        if not busy of w then exit repeat
    end repeat
    close it
end tell
EOF

}

terminal "$@"
```

### Issue

Currently, because of the use of `front window` I could change the focus after the window pops up to another terminal window then when the `do script` task completes `close it` will close the window I am currently focusing and not the window that actually ran the `do script`.

### Ideas

One idea I had in mind was to modify the AppleScript so that we get the `window id` of the window created from the AppleScript like the below. However, `close W` does not work.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set W to do script ""
    activate
    set S to do script "sleep 5" in W
    repeat
        delay 1
        if not busy of S then exit repeat
    end repeat
    close W
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this stackexchange [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31482904/2953889) you can store the window object then loop through.

You can then close the window you opened whether it is in focus or not.

```
    osascript <<EOF
    tell application "Terminal"
        set newTab to do script
        set current settings of newTab to settings set "Grass"
        set theWindow to first window of (every window whose tabs contains newTab)

        do script "$cmd" in newTab
        repeat
            delay 0.05
            if not busy of newTab then exit repeat
        end repeat

        repeat with i from 1 to the count of theWindow's tabs
            if item i of theWindow's tabs is newTab then close theWindow
        end repeat
    end tell
EOF
```

The `set current settings of newTab to settings set "Grass"` line isn't necessary - it is only to show the relevant window in a different colour.

Comment: Apologies for the delay.  The thing I noticed is the repeat loop where you reference `theWindow's tabs` explicitly, thus forcing the collection to be enumerated in every iteration of the loop. Instead, you could assign `theWindow's tabs` to a variable beforehand, then reference the for the `count` and the `item i of…`. In this case, there's only ever one tab, so it doesn't matter, but it in other situations, it'll be quicker and less work for AppleScript. Or, a repeat loop of the form `repeat with T in theWindow's tabs` means you only need `if T = newTab then...`, which is quicker still.

Answer (score 4):

The way to do this is very simple, and I left a comment to this effect against an earlier question:

> Depending what you wish to do, you might find the value of `w` in your AppleScript to be useful. The window that is created by `do script` returns an AppleScript reference to it (that you have assigned to `w`), which will be of the form `tab 1 of window id <number>`, where `<number>` is a five-or-so digit id number that remains fixed throughout the lifespan of the window. **You have to ignore the fact that the reference always contains `tab 1 of...`**, which is misleading since three tabs contained in a single window will all be `tab 1 of...` three distinct `id` numbers.

As you noticed, the `close` command does not apply to a `tab`, so you need the `window id`.  The reference created from any `do script` command gives you `tab 1 of window id...`, so you will always be able to reference the window which any particular `do script` command is running in:

```
tell application id "com.apple.Terminal"
    set T to do script "echo $$" --> btw, there's the pid number of the window's sub-shell
    set W to the id of window 1 where its tab 1 = T
        .
        .
     (* doing other stuff *)
        .
        .
    close window id W
end tell
```

Comment: This is neater than my answer

Comment: That’s nice of you to say. I already knew how to do it, and I think it’s a specific enough edge case you would probably only know if you have had to do it before.  Do you mind me providing a couple of notes about your script or is that patronising ?

Comment: If you have time please do - I'm a beginner at AppleScript.

Comment: @CJK hi, `set W to the id of window 1 where its tab 1 = T` line leads to an `error "Terminal got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000` error. Any idea why that might be? I checked and T is in the form you described "Tab 1 of Window #".

Comment: @HalilSen, almost all (or, in fact, probably _all_) AppleScript errors that return error number `-10000` are not caused by something the script is doing wrong in and of itself, but rather something that has gone wrong under the hood with AppleScript itself, often due to some object reference that gets handled incorrectly when messaging an application. Sometimes, a simple refactoring (syntactical changes that don't alter how the code functions) is all it takes to get around the problem, but it can require implementing a new approach altogether if that's an option. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ `-10000` errors are application-specific, and they _do_ have a specific cause, but it's a situation resembling the _"if you don't know, then I'm not going to tell you"_ sort of scenario. But this means that, while the problem will recur, the same problem will respond to the same solution from before, and it's just a matter of getting used to AppleScript's histrionics. I don't interact with _Terminal_ enough to have had this problem arise before, but it is worth trying a `whose` filter that predicates using an enumerated value rather than an object reference. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ What I mean by this is picking a property belonging to _Terminal_'s `tab` objects that you can have evaluated by the `whose` (`where`) filter as it compares it to the value of this same property for `T`.  A reliable predicate needs a property that is going to return a unique value for each `tab`, and one that is unlikely to change.  `tab` objects don't have an `id`, as far as I know, which is a shame. However, the `tty` property stores the terminal device open inside the `tab`, and this will definitely be unique, and _generally_ remain unchanged. Therefore, you could _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ first assign `tty of T` to a variable after the line in which `T` is declared by the call to **`do script`**.  Name it, say, `dev`, for example.  Then declare `W`: `set W to the id of (the first window where the tty of its tab 1 = dev)`.  Another option might be to avoid declaring `W` altogether, and obtain the reference to the window only at the point when you wish to close it, i.e. `close (the first window where its tab 1 = T)`; ***or***, to use the `tty` property here: `close (the first window whose tty of tab 1 = dev)` (remembering to declare `dev` after creating `T`). ☐

Comment: @CJK thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I "handled" my issue by activating the setting to close  "successfully exited" terminals automatically. Hopefully your explanation will help an other poor soul trying to make sense of AppleScript's shenanigans/